# Regexp aren't working with paragraph tags

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to fix some HTML, and it is working perfect. But one thing is givind me troubles; specifically the open and close `<p></p>` tags.
I need to fix two cases:
a) Remove the `<p> </p>` sequences.
b) Remove end and start blankspaces IN paragraphs.
I am doing this:

```
preg_replace("#<p>\s*</p>#","",$str);
preg_replace("#\s?(</?p>)\s?#", '$1', $str);
```

But none of both is replacing anything. What am I doing wrong, not tottaly right?

**Edit**: original code

```
$source=preg_replace("#\s?(</?p>)\s?#", '$1', $source); //Replace possible innecessary blank spaces
return preg_replace("#<p>\s*</p>#","",$source); //Delete all posible empty pharagraphs
```

Thank you :D

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: @JackManey it was quite funny... but, how else can I do it with an HTML parser? I am using HTMLpurifier and the coolest thing I can do is to fix some mistaken tags... but, the two required things? could you help me instead of just saying: "it's an impossible thing to do with regexps!".. and, making my question look like a negative nest?, why?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$source = preg_replace('#<p>\s*</p>|(?<=<p>)\s+|\s+(?=</p>)#', '', $source);
```

Use single quotes for clearer back-slashes. Did you mean \s or \\s? Luckily, in this case it doesn't matter.

The above PCRE will remove <p> </p> tags that only have whitespace (or nothing) between them, whitespace just after <p> and whitespace just before </p>. I don't see why your original code wouldn't have worked, though. You should have removed a single space both before or after any <p> or </p> tag (i.e. `" </p> "` would become `"</p>"`.

If you're still having trouble you need to post more code. Are you passing your variable in correctly, etc.? Try to write a minimal case with your problem and post the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it back to `$str`:

```
$str = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Be sure you are not dealing with some special kind of white spaces. If so, then use complex pattern:

```
$pattern = '/<p>(&nbsp;|[\s\p{Z}\p{C}\x85\xA0\x{0085}\x{00A0}\x{FFFD}]+)*<\/p>/iu';
```

To remove start and end blankspaces in paragraphs use patterns:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=<p>)(&nbsp;|[\s\p{Z}\p{C}\x85\xA0\x{0085}\x{00A0}\x{FFFD}]+)*/iu';
$pattern = '/(&nbsp;|[\s\p{Z}\p{C}\x85\xA0\x{0085}\x{00A0}\x{FFFD}]+)*(?=<\/p>)/iu';
```

Comment: jmm... I am doing it. But, why did you change the variable name? Is it incorrect to work with the function on the same variable as it is going to be assigned to?. I amg going to edit to leave the ORIGINAL code.

Answer (score 0):

Second regex will not work becasue there is no `</p>` anymore, you need to run this first. by why you need regex to remove whitespace you can use trim

```
$str = trim(preg_replace("#<p>(.*)</p>#Us", "$1", $str));
```

but you probably should not use regex to parse html as mention on stackoverflow lots of times.

EDIT:

```
preg_replace("/\s*<\/?p>\s*/", "", $str);
```

Comment: After the first replacement there is still a <p></p> sequence, because the only thing i am removing is the blankspace and recovering the `<p>`/`</p>`. With trim(), i don't think it would remove the intermediate blank spaces. I am using the html parser AFTER this, because first I need to do some BBCODE to HTML conversions. Thank you for the answer, but... are both expressions correct?

Comment: @Kenedy You have updated your code, I was refering to the first one. I update anwser with one regex.

Comment: Your edition still does not work. It is the same as mine changing the optional blank space by multiple blank spaces... why did i become so many negatives in my question? it is a true problem, and well explained... jmmm... :S

Comment: I forget about closing `/`. It remove tags in one call with spaces before and after tags.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the missing slash. But this is still the same as my example. It's that why I posted my question... because both examples (yours and mine) are WELL formed expressions... Thank you again, but... do you know why it could be having troubles?